# Retrive data from firebase with conditions

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to implement a one to one chat using firebase realtime database  ,    i insert messages with *senderid*,*Recieverid*,*message*,*date*,*sendername*,*Recievername*,
in my case different users are different chatrooms ,and i need to show this chatrooms for one to one chat rooms how can i implement in my android application

[image: This is my firebase database]

Here is my code for retrive data

```
private void append_chat_conversation(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    Iterator i = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();

    while (i.hasNext()){
        RecieverrId = (String) ((DataSnapshot)i.next()).getValue();
        datee = (String) ((DataSnapshot)i.next()).getValue();
        chat_msg = (String) ((DataSnapshot)i.next()).getValue();
        receiverrname = (String) ((DataSnapshot)i.next()).getValue();
        senderrid = (String) ((DataSnapshot)i.next()).getValue();
        chat_user_name = (String) ((DataSnapshot)i.next()).getValue();

        chat_conversation.append(chat_user_name +" : "+chat_msg +" \n");
    }


      }
```

but this code get all data from that chat room      ,
but i need to  dispaly  messsages  where sender name and receiver name are equal, sendername is getting from app user and reciever name is the name of chatroom,

please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have modeled the chat data in a way you'd model it in a SQL database: a single table with rows. You'll need to rethink this data model to fit better in a NoSQL system.

Firebase's query model is a bit more limited than what you get with the average relations DBMS. This means that you can't depend on queries as much as you're used to.

On the other hand: the Firebase Database allows for quite flexible data modeling. This in turn means that you can often adapt your data model to allow the queries that your app needs. This is a common theme when using NoSQL databases: you should model the data to fit with how your app wants to consume it. Often this means that your data model closely matches with what you show in the various screens of your app.

For a chat app, you're likely going to be showing either a list of chat rooms for a user or a single chat room that this user is part of. So given what I've just said, we should model these exact items in the database.

```
userChatrooms
  userid1
    chatroom1: true
    chatroom2: true
  userid2
    chatroom1: true
    chatroom3: true
chatrooms
  chatroom1
    chatmsg1
      senderid: ...
      receiverid: ...
```

With this model you can now easily determine the list of chat rooms for a user: `/userChatrooms/{aut.uid}`.

For a great introduction read the [Firebase documentation on data structuring](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data), this [article on NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and watch our video series [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s).